# How to convert multidimensional array from PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I try a little with dygraph. I get my data from an ajax call and I need to convert my returned JSON array to a JavaScript array.

Now my dygraph options look like this

```
    series = {
      sample1: {
        color: 'Green',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        pointSize: 4
      },
      sample2: {
        color: 'DarkBlue',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        pointSize: 3
      },
      sample3: {
        color: 'DarkOrange',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 2
      }
    }

   dygraph_options = {
      title: title,
      labels: jsonDataTable.labels,
      series: series,
      ...
   }
```

My php ajax call look like this:

```
$series = array();
$series[] = array( 'sample1' => array('color' => 'Green'));
$series[] = array( 'sample2' => array('color' => 'DarkBlue'));
$series[] = array( 'sample3' => array('color' => 'DarkOrange'));

$table = array( "series" => $series, "labels" => $labels, "data" => $rows );
return $table;
```

I want to get the series from json. But my returned series are different from the javascript series:

> jsonDataTable.series -> [Object { stock={...}}, Object {
>   forecast={...}}]
>   javascript series -> Object { stock={...}, 
>   forecast={...},  training={...}}

I try a lot but can't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `$series` to be an associative array:

```
$series = array();
$series['sample1'] = array('color' => 'Green');
$series['sample2'] = array('color' => 'DarkBlue');
$series['sample3'] = array('color' => 'DarkOrange');
```

Or

```
$series = array(
   'sample1' => array('color' => 'Green'),
   'sample2' => array('color' => 'DarkBlue'),
   'sample3' => array('color' => 'DarkOrange')
);
```

Comment: Oh my got the associative array is exactly what I want and it is soo easy, why did not I try this??? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Prepare array to send from php to javascript:

```
echo json_encode( $array );
```

Translate the data in javascript to a nice object

```
var a = JSON.parse( phpdata );
```

Prep to send data to php from javascript

```
var tosend = JSON.stringify( a );
```

Translate incoming js object back into php

```
$a = json_decode( $some_json );
```

or

```
$a = json_decode( $some_json, true );
```